# How to retrieve all documents in elasticsearch

Tags: json

I am a novice in ES and need help.

Here is my data set from JSON

```
{
    "simplewiki": {
        "page": [{
                "index": {
                    "_index": "myindex",
                    "_type": "wiki",
                    "_id": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "April",
                "url": "https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/April",
                "abstract": "April is the 4th month of the year, and comes between March and May. It is one of four months to have 30 days.",
                "sections": ["The Month", "April in poetry", "Events in April", "Fixed Events", "Moveable Events", "Selection of Historical Events", "Trivia", "References"]
            },

            {
                "index": {
                    "_index": "myindex",
                    "_type": "wiki",
                    "_id": "2"
                }
            },
            {
                "title": "August",
                "url": "https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/August",
                "abstract": "August (Aug.) is the 8th month of the year in the Gregorian calendar, coming between July and September.",
                "sections": ["The Month", "August observances", "Fixed observances and events", "Moveable and Monthlong events", "Selection of Historical Events", "Trivia", "References"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

question is  that I used the below command to index:
curl -XPOST locahost:9200/myindex/wiki --data-binary @wiki.json

After execution: (52) Empty reply from server and total 2 successful 1 and failed 0.
When I use command : curl -XGET localhost:92200/myindex/wiki/1?pretty?

I get the below but not all the details and found is false.

```
{
  "_index":"myindex",
  "_type":"wiki",
  "_id":"1",
  "found" :false
}
```

How do I ensure found is true and the whole title and abstract are retrieved. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you attach your received message after posting data? (I cannot add a comment now)

You can read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#_automatic_id_generation) and try again.

Comment: Here is the message after the curl command {"_index":"myindex","_type":"wiki","_id":"AV811U-X_pQ5CpohrUQD","_version":"1","result":created","_shared":{"total:2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"created":true"}

Comment: When I execute the command :curl -XGET localhost:92200/myindex/wiki/1?pretty? I am expecting something like below {
  "_index":"myindex",
  "_type":"wiki",
  "_id":"1",
  "found" : true                                                                                                  
"_source:" { " abstract " : " April is ....." , "title : "April","url":"https://simple.wikipedia.og/wiki/Apirl","sections:  [....]}}}